# Is it possible to create a tab, such that it has tab history (via the brower's back button)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

If I use `chrome.tabs.create` to create a tab with URL 1, and then use `chrome.tabs.update` to navigate it to URL 2, the user can't use the "back" button to manually go back to URL 1.

There is the `window.history.pushState()` method, which can be triggered via a content script, but that approach will only work if both URLs have the same origin.

Is there a way to make this work? The objective is to be able to create a tab that has a history that can be accessed via the "back" button.

Comment: Try injecting a content script in the first url and either use location.assign or append `<a>` element to the page and then elem.click()

Comment: Or do it within one site (the final one): do pushState right after injection with the same URL and then intercept `navigation.onnavigate` event so when it triggers you'call location.assign to redirect to the other site.